# AspectJ cannot find .raw superclass

Tags: java, mockito, gradle-plugin, aspect, compile-time-weaving

## Background

A project uses Aspects for logging. The particulars:

- Java 11
- [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php) 1.9.4 (runtime, tools, compiler, post-compile-weaving plugin)
- Mockito Core 2.25.1

The `build.gradle` file resembles:

```
apply plugin: "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving"

dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.12.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.osgi', name: 'org.osgi.framework', version: '1.9.0'
    compileOnly group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.25.1'

    inpath project(":company.project.main")
}
```

## Problem

When the application is compiled, AspectJ cannot find `MockMethodDispatcher`, and reports an error:

```
.../mockito-core-2.25.1.jar [error] can't determine superclass of missing type org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.inject.MockMethodDispatcher
when weaving type org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
(no source information available)
        [Xlint:cantFindType]
.../org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/e8fa2864b65c0b6fbb20daa436a94853bcd17e5e/mockito-core-2.25.1.jar [warning] can't find type org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.inject.MockMethodDispatcher whilst determining signatures of call or execution join point for java.util.concurrent.Callable org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice.handle(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[]), this may cause a pointcut to fail to match at this join point 
when weaving type org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodAdvice
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindTypeAffectingJPMatch]
```

I suspect this is because the file is stored as a `.raw` file rather than a `.class` file (as per [issue 845](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/845)):

```
1778 Mon Jul 08 13:47:02 PDT 2019 org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/inject/MockMethodDispatcher.raw
```

## Question

How would you update the Gradle file to instruct the [post-compile-weaving](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving) plugin to ignore weaving (or scanning) Mockito classes altogether?

## Notes

From the command-line, weaving appears to work:

```sh
java -cp aspectjtools-1.9.4.jar:aspectjrt-1.9.4.jar org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main \
-inpath application.jar \
-aspectpath ../aspects/build/classes/java/main \
-Xlint:warning \
-verbose \
-showWeaveInfo \
-log aop.log \
-outjar woven.jar
```

Though the output classes in `woven.jar` should be injected into `application.jar`.

## Addendum

Note:

- Working around the issue by adorning the `@Aspect`-annotated class with a `!within` `@Pointcut` annotation is not viable. Would strongly prefer to pass an argument to [`ajc`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html) via the plugin.
- Downgrading `cantFindType` from an error to a warning would be a satisfactory answer, but not ideal (stuck on syntax), as I'd like other `cantFindType` errors to remain as errors.

## Related

- [Gradle and AspectJ - avoid weaving my own packages during compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826638/gradle-and-aspectj-avoid-weaving-my-own-packages-during-compile-time)
- [How to set "-aspectpath" for the FreeFair AspectJ Gradle Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221848/how-to-set-aspectpath-for-the-freefair-aspectj-gradle-plugin)
- [AspectJ + Gradle configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949541/aspectj-gradle-configuration)

## Attempts

When calling `compileJava` as follows:

```
compileJava {
    ajc {
        enabled = true
        classpath = configurations.aspectj
        options {
            aspectpath = configurations.aspect
            compilerArgs = [""]
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle reports the following error:

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'classpath' for object of type `io.freefair.gradle.plugins.aspectj.AjcAction`.

Using:

```
compileJava {
  ajc {
    options {
      compilerArgs = [""]
    }
  }
}
```

Gradle reports:

> Could not find method options() for arguments [...] on object of type `io.freefair.gradle.plugins.aspectj.AjcAction`.

The [source code](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/blob/master/aspectj-plugin/src/main/java/io/freefair/gradle/plugins/aspectj/AjcAction.java) on master seems to expose different names for its "configurable things":

```java
task.getInputs().property("ajcArgs", this.getOptions().getCompilerArgs())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declared dependency is transitive:

```
inpath project(":company.project.main")
```

This will pass the complete runtime classpath of `:company.project.main` (the classes produced by said project *and* all its dependencies) into the `-inpath` of ajc. (See the `build/tmp/compileJava/ajc.options` file to confirm.)

To avoid weaving advices into external classes, declare a [non-transitive dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sub:disabling_resolution_transitive_dependencies) as follows:

```
inpath(project(":company.project.main")) { 
    transitive = false
}
```

Depending on your exact requirements and your project structure, it might be a better approach to apply the `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving` plugin directly to the `:company.project.main` project.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the above answer (that helped me a lot, thanks!), you can also apply this strategy to transitive dependencies that are present in external dependencies, for example:

```
    inpath('org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:3.1.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
```